# How to Remove the Card from the Google Pay Wallet

Tags: android, google-pay

I was developing an Android App and was able to save my Card in Google wallet using:-
[https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/{jwt_generated}](https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/%7Bjwt_generated%7D)

After, I add the card to the Pay App. How can I remove the card from the Pay App?

Does Google have an API that can help me to remove the added card from the Google App?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/wallet/retail/loyalty-cards/rest/v1/loyaltyobject#methods), there is no API to remove the card.

> - addmessage
> - get
> - insert
> - list
> - modifylinkedofferobjects
> - patch
> - update

The user needs to initiate the delete, this can be done be navigating the user to: `https://pay.google.com/gp/v/object/{issuerId}.{identifier}`

Once on this page they can use the three vertical dots in the top right corner of the pass to **Remove** the pass themselves.

Comment: Are we sure there is no API to remove the card programmatically? Apple wallet allows this :S